# merge arrays in python based on a similar value

Tags: python

I want to merge two arrays in python based on the first element in each column of each array.

For example,

```
A = ([[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[4, 6, 7],
[5, 7, 8], 
[5, 9, 1]])

B = ([[1, .002],
[4, .005],
[5, .006]])
```

So that I get an array

```
C = ([[1, 2, 3, .002],
[4, 5, 6, .005],
[4, 6, 7, .005],
[5, 7, 8, .006],
[5, 9, 1, .006]])
```

For more clarity:

First column in A is 1, 4, 4, 5, 5 and
First column of B is 1, 4, 5

So that 1 in A matches up with 1 in B and gets .002

How would I do this in python? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are the rows sorted by the first element? Because in your example they are sorted this way. If this was true then you could probably avoid using `dict` and obtain a faster solution(e.g. I believe `itertools.groupby` could help).

Comment: Could `B` have more than 2 columns?

Comment: Yes the rows are sorted by the first element.

Comment: In my case B could have up to 3 columns. But in general I don't see why B couldn't have more.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Ok to modify `A` in place?:

```
d = dict((x[0],x[1:]) for x in B)
```

Now `d` is a dictionary where the first column are keys and the subsequent columns are values.

```
for lst in A:
    if lst[0] in d: #Is the first value something that we can extend?
        lst.extend(d[lst[0]])

print A
```

To do it out of place (inspired by the answer by Ashwini):

```
d = dict((x[0],x[1:]) for x in B)
C = [lst + d.get(lst[0],[]) for lst in A]
```

However, with this approach, you *need* to have lists in both A and B.  If you have some lists and some tuples it'll fail (although it could be worked around if you needed to), but it will complicate the code slightly.

**with either of these answers, `B` can have an arbitrary number of columns**

As a side note on style:  I would write the lists as:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [4, 6, 7],
     [5, 7, 8], 
     [5, 9, 1]]
```

Where I've dropped the parenthesis ... They make it look too much like you're putting a list in a `tuple`.  Python's automatic line continuation happens with parenthesis `()`, square brackets `[]` or braces `{}`.

Comment: Maybe the Op isn't aware that also brackets `[`,`]`(and braces) provide automatic line continuation, and not only the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

*(This answer assumes these are just regular lists. If they’re NumPy arrays, you have more options.)*

It looks like you want to use B as a lookup table to find values to add to each row of A.

I would start by making a dictionary out of the data in B. As it happens, B is already in just the right form to be passed to the `dict()` builtin:

```
B_dict = dict(B)
```

Then you just need to build C row by row.

For each row in A, `row[0]` is the first element, so `B_dict[row[0]]` is the value you want to add to the end of the row. Therefore `row + [B_dict[row[0]]` is the row you want to add to C.

Here is a list comprehension that builds C from A and B_dict.

```
C = [row + [B_dict[row[0]]] for row in A]
```

Comment: They are NumPy arrays, what I can I do differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `B` to a `dictionary` first, with the first element of each sublist as key and second one as value.

Then simply iterate over `A` and append the related value fetched from the dict.

```
In [114]: A = ([1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[4, 6, 7],
[5, 7, 8], 
[6, 9, 1])

In [115]: B = ([1, .002],
[4, .005],
[5, .006])

In [116]: [x + [dic[x[0]]] if x[0] in dic else []  for x in A]
Out[116]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 0.002],
 [4, 5, 6, 0.005],
 [4, 6, 7, 0.005],
 [5, 7, 8, 0.006],
 [6, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: I don't think you need to `map(tuple,B))` -- I think that just `dic = dict(B)` would work ...

Comment: Also, this will fail is `A` has an item in the first column that `B` doesn't have ... I don't think you could even work around this one with a `dic.get()` since your items in `dic` aren't lists.

Comment: @mgilson Good point, I guess that can be fixed easily by using `dict.get`.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, but it can't be with the way your `dic` is set up. (which inspired me to append to my answer).  You need `[dic.get(x[0],???)]` to evaulate to an empty list which is impossible as far as I can see...

Comment: @mgilson we can use the ternary operator here.

Comment: Ahh... right then.  ternary operator works. Or "conditional expression" if we want to get the semantics correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `itertools.product()` that prevents having to create a dictionary for B:

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: [lst_a + lst_b[1:] for (lst_a, lst_b) in product(A, B) if lst_a[0] == lst_b[0]]
Out[2]:
[[1, 2, 3, 0.002],
 [4, 5, 6, 0.005],
 [4, 6, 7, 0.005],
 [5, 7, 8, 0.006],
 [5, 9, 1, 0.006]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive, simple way:

```
for alist in A:
    for blist in B:
        if blist[0] == alist[0]:
            alist.extend(blist[1:])
            # alist.append(blist[1]) if B will only ever contain 2-tuples.
            break  # Remove this if you want to append more than one.
```

The downside here is that it's O(N^2) complexity. For most small data sets, that should be ok. If you're looking for something more comprehensive, you'll probably want to look at @mgilson's answer. Some comparison:

1. His response converts everything in `B` to a dict and performs list slicing on each element. If you have a lot of values in `B`, that could be expensive. This uses the existing lists (you're only looking at the first value, anyway).
2. Because he's using dicts, he gets O(1) lookup times (his answer also assumes that you're never going to append multiple values to the end of the values in `A`). That means overall, his algorithm will achieve O(N). You'll need to weigh whether the overhead of creating a dict is going to outweight the iteration of the values in `B`.